# Пробелы после сокращений

Tags: пунктуация

Ставятся ли пробелы после точки в сокращениях: *и т.()д.*, *и т.()п.*, а также в инициалах, *И.()И. Иванов*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По правилам, принятым в России, пробел обязателен после **любой** точки.
Я не говорю сейчас о формулах, таблицах  и числах в цифровой записи. 
Де-факто в инициалах это правило соблюдают через раз, а в "и т.д." и "и т.п." - почти никогда.  Правда надо иметь в виду, что в обычном тексте появление даже таких сокращений само по себе не является вполне нормативным, а потому и написание строго не регламентируется.

Answer (score 2):

В ГОСТе по делопроизводству примеры, где инициалы пишутся перед фамилией, приведены без пробелов.

> Должность лица, которому адресован документ, указывают в дательном падеже, например:

```
                                                   Генеральному директору
                                                   ОАО "Северные регионы"
                                                   В.А.Лагунину
```

UPD Нет, сори, это не так. ГОСТ тут ни при чем. На другом сайте:

> В.А. Лагунину

Comment: Что за ГОСТ такой?

Есть какой-то подозрительный нормирующий документ - неизвестного уровня.

support.ursmu.ru/Files/Prikaz197-1_2010_Pril5.doc‎  
Но там пробел по крайней мере перед фамилией.

Comment: ГОСТ Р 6.30-2003

Хотя в ГОСТЕ это и не регламентируется. Читаю этот же ГОСТ на других сайтах - там с пробелами...

Comment: Да, забавно... 
Остается надеться, что это ошибки верстки.